# What is the purpose of specifying a "control" in an A/B/N split test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, presentation

I define *control* as the currently accepted, best known variation.

The test to be performed would introduce *n* new variations. Each variation will be served randomly for the duration of the test.

I am interested in answering this question in terms of the following goals:

- determining if/when there is a statistically significant winner/loser
- effectively communicating the results of the split test

I am currently comparing the performance of each variation to the total average performance instead of to the performance of the control variation.

Should I consider a different definition of *control*?

Comment: The average performance is not a relevant baseline for comparisons, since you can't launch a mixture of all the tests. The control seems better suited here. You need to compare $T_1-C, T_2-C,...,T_K-C$ to see which one biggest and if that is statistically meaningful given the variation. The precise details of the test(s) depend on your business goals.

Comment: Are the treatments ordered in any way (say increasing discounts)?

Answer (score 1):

> Should I consider a different definition of control?

Yes you absolutely should!

Comparing to the "average" performance is just asking to be dooped by regression to the mean.  Some variants will naturally perform worse than the average, but they might do better than business as usual.  That would be a win.

Additionally, your comment "determining if/**when** there is a statistically significant winner/loser" makes me worried about peeking.  You should not be peeking or checking if the result is statistically significant yet.  Unless done correctly, that will destroy the validity of the experiment.

Stick to traditional designs.  Keep $n$ small, use business as usual as the control, and either end the experiment when you've attained your prespecified sample size or use techniques which allow for intermittent analysis.